# Using NumPy to convert user/item ratings into 2-D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, pandas

With performing some classificion using some user/item/rating data.  My issue is how to I convert these 3 columns into a matrix of user(row), item(columns) and the ratings data populating the matrix.

```
User  Item  ItemRating
1     23    3
2     204   4
1     492   2
3     23    4
```

and so on.  I tried using DataFrame but was getting NULL errors.

Comment: How is it stored now? Is that a text file, or some kind of numpy or pandas object?

Comment: And i can only use NumPy to perform this operation reading from a text file.  There is no header information in the text file.

Comment: You can load it then using `arr = np.genfromtxt(filname, dtype=int)`  If the first row does say `"User  Item  ItemRating"`, then use `arr = np.genfromtxt(filname, skip_header=1, dtype=int)`

Comment: If you want to build the entire thing using numpy only (no pandas dependency) see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17028329/1730674

Comment: great!  thanks again for the knowledge.  very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi.  I am getting an error when I use this as my document read command:  arr = np.genfromtxt("u_clean.data", skip_header=1)ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #3 (got 3 columns instead of 1), etc....for every odd number line.

Comment: Your file must have the same number of values per line (to fill a uniform array).  It seems like one of your lines has only `1` value in it, but then a later line (#3) has three values in it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is pivot, if I get your idea right, with pandas it will be as follows.

Load data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep='\s+', header=None)
df.columns = ['User','Item','ItemRating']
```

Pivot it:

```
>>> df
   User  Item  ItemRating
0     1    23           3
1     2   204           4
2     1   492           2
3     3    23           4
>>> df.pivot(index='User', columns='Item', values='ItemRating')
Item  23   204  492
User
1       3  NaN    2
2     NaN    4  NaN
3       4  NaN  NaN
```

For a numpy example, let's emulate file with `StringIO`:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
data ="""1     23    3
2     204   4
1     492   2
3     23    4"""
```

and load it:

```
>>> arr = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(data), dtype=int)
>>> arr
array([[  1,  23,  3],
       [  2, 204,  4],
       [  1, 492,  2],
       [  3,  23,  4]])
```

pivot is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028329/python-create-a-pivot-table)

```
rows, row_pos = np.unique(arr[:, 0], return_inverse=True)
cols, col_pos = np.unique(arr[:, 1], return_inverse=True)
rows, row_pos = np.unique(arr[:, 0], return_inverse=True)
cols, col_pos = np.unique(arr[:, 1], return_inverse=True)
pivot_table = np.zeros((len(rows), len(cols)), dtype=arr.dtype)
pivot_table[row_pos, col_pos] = arr[:, 2]
```

and the result:

```
>>> pivot_table
array([[ 3,  0,  2],
       [ 0,  4,  0],
       [ 4,  0,  0]])
```

Note that results differ, as in second approach non-existing values are set to zero.

Select one that suits you better ;)

Comment: Heh, glad you were able to parse that :)

Comment: @askewchan If you mean parsing raw data to dataframe, I do it each second pandas question, so just need to consult my own previous answers :)

Comment: I meant understanding the question :P

Comment: thanks and sorry if there was confusion in my problem statement.  i am just learning python and programming concurrently and have little experience in stating the problem statement correctly.  Do you need to bring in any additional add-in-s like panda, etc...

Comment: if i have text file can i just read in the data vy np.genfromtxt()?  Then perform the pivot?

Comment: thank you so much alko.  unfortunately i need to use only NumPy commands to perform this task since I have to perform some classification afterwards using previously learned numpy functions.

Comment: @user2822055 see for numpy and difference in result. Btw, you can get numpy underlying array for a dataframe with `df.values`

Comment: @user2822055 It's not that you asked poorly, it's that I wasn't familiar with a pivot table until alko used the word and I was able to look it up :P